# Using SQL to retrieve the most popular queries in a dataset

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of data with fields: `search, search_location, num_searches`. I want to put together a `SELECT` statement that will generate a list of the 100 most popular `search_locations`, determined by the `SUM()` of the `num_searches` field for all searches with the same `search_location` (regardless of the value of the `search` field). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a GROUP BY, a method that reduces a table by grouping all rows that share some of the same values.

```
SELECT search_location, SUM(num_searches) as total_searches
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY search_location
    ORDER BY total_searches DESC
    LIMIT 100;
```